# AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all' (NameError)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrapy

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=("http://finance.naver.com/news/mainnews.nhn")

r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

a_data = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"block1"})

for item in a_data:
    print item.contents[0].find_all("dt",{"class":"articleSubject"})[0].text
```

In this code, when i run this code. I have error like this.
"AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'"

How can i solve this problem ????
I have already tried try and except method. However, it didn't work...

// Html code

```
<li class="block1">
<dl>
<dt class="articleSubject">
<span class="remark"></span> <!-- 말머리는 span class="remark" 로 묶임 -->
<a href="/news/news_read.nhn?       
article_id=0003289339&amp;office_id=009&amp;mode=mainnews&amp;type=&amp;date=2014-08-   
27&amp;page=1">**시총 9조 `모바일 공룡` 다음카카오 합병 승인…업계 지각변동 예고**</a>
</dt>
<dd class="articleSummary">
다음카카오가 합병을 위한 마지막 문턱을 넘어섰다. 네이버의 독주가 지속되고 있는 온라인·모바일 업계에    
적지 않은 시장 판도 변화가 예상된다.   27일 다음과 카카오는 각각 제주 ..
                                    <span class="press">매일경제 </span>
<span class="bar">|</span>
<span class="wdate">2014-08-27 11:40:05</span>
</dd>
</dl>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to find the text associated with the `dt` with the `class` attribute `articleSubject`, you can directly find it within the `item`.

By doing this:

```
>>> for item in a_data:
...     print item.find_all("dt",{"class":"articleSubject"})[0].text
```

This prints:

```
**시총 9조 `모바일 공룡` 다음카카오 합병 승인…업계 지각변동 예고**
```

for the above HTML. If you run this code against the URL in your code, you will get 20 results.

`item.contents` is a list with `\n` as the first item. So doing a `find_all()` on a new line character throws the `AttributeError`

Comment: Instead of `find_all(...)[0]`, use `find(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate in your loop NavigableStrings from tags. First:

```
import NavigableString
```

then in your loop test all the elements in the soup to see if they are tags or NavigableStrings by using:

```
if isinstance(object, NavigableString):
    Do something with this event
else:
    Do something with thing that is not NavigableString
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code that NavigableString is imported from bs4